# How to attach each sheet as attachment from a excel file (workbook) to send mail

Tags: excel, vba

How to send an email by attaching the each sheet as individual attachment.

I have a workbook it contains 3 or 4 sheets, i want attach these sheets as individual attachment to send a mail.

Any help in this regards is highly solicited.

Thanks in advance

Comment: A sheet is not a file, `specific_worksheet.saveas()` to generate a new .xls/x *workbook* for each, then send those.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Is there any possibility to provide the VBA code for this... beacuse i am not well versed with excel vba.

Thanks

Comment: I just gave you a link which is full of VBA examples?

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the Workbook from VBA and then process each of the sheets. Even not using VBA in Excel you need to have Excel running for getting the sheet information. The [examples](http://www.rondebruin.nl/sendmail.htm) mentioned by @siddharth-rout give code on how to create the email for Sendmail and several Mail program.

Go for Sendmail as you can dispense with user interaction and when you can provide the target in the program (or from some cell in the workbook). Go with the mailer routines for the mailer your users have installed if they need to provide comments in addition to the sheets or the email target addresses.